# Can a CT scan have advserse cognitive effects on the brain?

Tags: neuroscience, neuroimaging, neurology

If the normal Xrays scans, despite the low amount of radiation (equivalent to a few hours of background radiation, can be sufficient to cause a burning sensation, then I wonder if the much higher dose of a CT head scan can cause some adverse cognitive effects?
Also, is it possible that the Xrays make the neurons fire at random?

Comment: This question is most likely going to get closed as off-topic for this site. Sorry. This is not a great place for medical questions for two reasons, one is that it's hard/impossible to get all the relevant information in a question, and two, we're a bunch of unqualified randoms here. This one's a question for your doctor.